# How do I sign amazon apk?

Tags: android, apk, digital-signature, jarsigner

I am trying to sign an amazon wrapped apk so i can load my app to the amazon app store.  I have to do this because my app uses Google Apis.  All the tutorials on this are complicated when it comes to explaining how to use jarsigner.  How do I access jarsigner from eclipse?  Can i access it as easily as Android Tools..Export Signed Application?

EDIT

Using [this](http://dimitar.me/how-to-sign-an-unsigned-android-package-apk-file/) tutorial I was able to access jarsigner via command line, but when i entered my password for my keystore it said "jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: and.  and must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain." I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Amazon doesn't have its own APK format - it uses Android's default APK format. In Eclipse, go to ProjectName -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package.

You will have to create a keystore to sign the application.  Remember to keep the keystore credentials in a safe place, it's easy to forget!

Comment: Thanks for responding, but i am trying to resign my apk, because it uses Google Apis. Like in this tutorial here http://www.smargav.com/post/signing-app-for-amazon-app-store/ .  I am having trouble finding/using jarsigner.

Comment: This is strange.  I have an app on both the Amazon app store and Google Play, both signed through Eclipse (Which probably uses jarsigner underneath).  What it wants you to do is open a CMD window and manually use the jarsigner app to sign the app

Comment: Yeah, im having trouble accessing the jarsigner through command prompt.  Didn't know whether there was an easier way of not.

Comment: Did you add the JDK path to your PATH variable?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that.  Do I do that through build path dialog?

Comment: No, it's a windows path thing... right click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced Tab, click on Environment Variables. Under "System Variables" double click on "Path".  At the very end of that string add a semi-colon, followed by the /bin directory of your JDK, usually located at "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1-7\bin". After you add that, click "OK" and close everything.  Then you should be able to use Jarsigner from a cmd window

Comment: I still can't access it. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't work.  I read somewhere that you can upload your UNSIGNED app to Amazon, and they will sign it for you... check out this link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697191/how-do-i-sign-amazon-apk/12697375#comment17142824_12697375